# Android sinch instant messaging start from notification builder

Tags: android, sinch

I followed sinch [tutorial](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/) for making a messaging application. Based on this tutorial the sinch client starts at the main activity. I am able to send push notifications using Parse and create a notification builder but when user taps that, obviously the sinch client is not initiated and thus it doesn't work. 
How can I run sinch client from a pendingIntent in notification builder that takes me directly to the MessagingActivity? Where and how should I call the MessagingService and the BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: I highly suggest using Google Cloud messaging instead of since. SInch doesnt save you work in the end. And GCM has much better documentation and SO posts to help you through. I worked with sinch for 3 weeks, got nowhere. I build my own in GCM, took 1 week. Food for thought

Comment: Thanks. I was also a bit disappointed about it. They need to do a lot more I feel.

Comment: ya, conceptually it is decent. The execution is buggy to say the least.

Comment: Yea.. I've been dealing with issue in push notification as well. I'll give it one more chance and if I couldnt fix this I should move on. Do you have any idea how I can execute the service while the app is closed from a push notification?

Comment: in gcm it is super easy. Get a reg token, subscribe to a topic, and then in the backend do a POST to the topic. I send push notifications to over 1 million users a week. works really well.

Comment: thanks. Let me see what I can do about it.

Comment: good luck. If you make SO posts about it, please tag me in the comments. I'm happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your notification method you can add this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ID, senderId);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_NAME, name);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

instead of `MainActivity.class` you change it to `MessagingActivity.class` and put the extras that you want using `intent.putExtra()` .

Comment: Sure, but then how do I start the service? In many cases the service might just stop. Do I need to start the service in BroadcastReceiver as well?

Comment: for me I just start my service from `GCMIntentService` whenever I get a new push like this: `private void connectToService() {
        getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, SinchClientService.class), GcmIntentService.this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }`, and then I call `connectToService()` in `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`,  don't forget to let `GCMIntentService` implement `ServiceConnection`, then in `onServiceConnected` you add what you need to do.